# Save/Get UIColor from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, string, uicolor, userdefaults, nskeyedunarchiver

I need some help to load and read UIColor from UserDefaults.

I found a nice extension to do that:

```
extension UserDefaults {
 func colorForKey(key: String) -> UIColor? {
  var color: UIColor?
  if let colorData = data(forKey: key) {
   color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
  }
  return color
 }

 func setColor(color: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
  var colorData: NSData?
   if let color = color {
    colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color) as NSData?
  }
  set(colorData, forKey: key)
 }

}
```

But NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject was deprecated recently, so i don't know how to get data from it.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, simply replace 2 lines, i.e

Replace

`color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor`

with

`color = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData)`

//// Here you can use `try?` instead of `try!` and wrap it in `if-let` statement. Your choice.

**and**

Replace

`colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color) as NSData?`

with

`colorData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: true)`

Also, use `Data` instead of `NSData` in `var colorData: NSData?` ,i.e.

```
var colorData: Data?
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do as do the deprecation messages tell you:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func colorForKey(key: String) -> UIColor? {
        if let colorData = data(forKey: key),
            let color = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData)
        {
            return color
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    // But why an Option<UIColor> here?
    func setColor(color: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
        if let color = color,
            let colorData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        {
            set(colorData, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "why an Optional<UIColor> here?" As in why does the function `setColor(color:forKey)` take an `Optional` parameter for the `Color`?